# Confusion over the second argument of the DATEDIFF function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've referred to [this on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258269%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) but I'm still unsure what the second argument in the DATEDIFF function is doing in the following two examples:

`SELECT DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate())`  --run on 14 Aug this returns 112

`SELECT DATEDIFF(yy,1000,getdate())`  --I chose 1000 arbitrarily and run on 14 Aug this returns 110

Usually I'll use `DATEDIFF` to find the number of days, or number of years between two months and the second argument is then a date.

Reason I'd like to understand the above is to ultimately understand the following:

`SELECT DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()), 0)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use an integer as the second argument (or for any datetime/smalldatetime assignment for that matter), this is interpreted as the number of days since 1900-01-01.

```
DECLARE @d1 DATETIME = 0, @d2 DATETIME = 1;
SELECT @d1, @d2;
```

Result:

```
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000    1900-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

Note that this doesn't work for new data types like `DATE` during direct assignment:

```
DECLARE @d DATE = 0;
```

Result:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

But it can still work using date math, e.g.:

```
DECLARE @d DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, 0, SYSDATETIME());
SELECT @d;
```

Result:

```
2012-08-14
```

For these inconsistent reasons, I recommend you use proper date literals so that it is clear which date you mean and so that it works regardless of the data type. This is a habit I find hard to break, since typing 0 is so much easier than `19000101`...

Comment: so if I have the second arg as 1000 then it is 1000 days after 1900-01-01 ?

Comment: @whytheq: A simple test seems tell me if the second argument is 1000, it is indeed 1000 days after 1900-01-01. After some tests, I figure: If the second parameter is an integer, it is interpreted as that number of days after 1900-01-01.

Answer (score 5):

Consider below example to understand this concept better. 0 is default date `"1900-01-01"`

Below Query gives output as **`2017-10-31 00:00:00.000`**

```
SELECT    DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,SYSDATETIME())+3, 0))
```

Dividing the above query into various parts to understand the calculation.

```
-- 1414 Months since '1900-01-01'
    SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,SYSDATETIME())  + 3 

-- adding 1414 Months to Default date 1900 Produces '2017-11-01 00:00:00.000'
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,SYSDATETIME())+3, 0) 

--Subtract 1 day from '2017-11-01 00:00:00:000' gives last day of previous month.
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,SYSDATETIME())+3, 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to datediff() is a date.

The first example returns the "start" date of time in the SQL Server world.  That would be 112 years before the current date.

The second example is rather non-sensical.  As implemented, the dates are represented as number days since the earliest date.  This is the number of years since 1000 days after the earliest date.

The last example adds a number of years to the base date.  It then adds a number of months.  Since the base date is 1/1/1900, this is giving you the first date of the day after the nth month in the yth year.